# Binance order error Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action

Tags: php, binance

"code" => -2015
"msg" => "Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action."

I get this error when I try to place a **STOP LOSS ** order on the binance api.

I have done the following;

1. Whitelist my IP address in the api management
2. Tried placing the order manually on binance and it was opened.
3. Checked the trading permission on the api management

Below is my code snippet

```
function getPricision($symbol)
{
    // Make a request to get the symbol details
    $symbol_info = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo?symbol=' . $symbol), true);
    if (isset($symbol_info['symbols']) && !empty($symbol_info['symbols'])) {
        // Get the first symbol in the list (assuming there's only one matching symbol)
        $symbol_data = $symbol_info['symbols'][0];

        // Find the lot size filter
        $lot_size_filter = array_filter($symbol_data['filters'], function ($filter) {
            return $filter['filterType'] === 'LOT_SIZE';
        });

        // Check if the lot size filter is found
        if (!empty($lot_size_filter)) {
            $lot_size = floatval($lot_size_filter[1]['stepSize']);
            $precision = intval(round(-log10($lot_size), 0));

            return $precision;
        }
    }

    return false;
}


    // Set the required parameters for the limit trade
    $api_key = env('BINANCE_API_KEY');
    $api_secret = env('BINANCE_SECRET_KEY');
    $api_endpoint = 'https://api.binance.com';
    $symbol = 'ALGOUSDT';
    $side = 'BUY';
    
    $entryPrice = 0.1487;
    
    $side = 'BUY';
    $order_type = 'STOP_LOSS';
    $stop_price = $entryPrice; 
    $limit_price = $entryPrice; 
    $amount = 20; // Set the amount 
    
    
    // Calculate the quantity based on the desired amount
    $quantity = $amount / $limit_price;
    
    // Format the quantity, stop price, and limit price to the correct precision
    $formatted_quantity = number_format($quantity, getPricision($symbol), '.', '');
    
    // Create the order payload
    $timestamp = time() * 1000;
    $params = [
        'symbol' => $symbol,
        'side' => $side,
        'type' => $order_type,
        'quantity' => $formatted_quantity,
        'stopPrice' => $stop_price,
        'price' => $limit_price,
        'timeInForce' => 'GTC', // Good 'Til Canceled
        'timestamp' => $timestamp,
    ];
    
    //dd($params);
    // Generate the query string and sign it
    $query_string = http_build_query($params);
    $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $query_string, $api_secret);
    $params['signature'] = $signature;
    
    // Send the signed request to place the order
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint . '/api/v3/order');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string . '&signature=' . $signature);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['X-MBX-APIKEY: ' . $api_key]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    
    // Process the response
    $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
    if (isset($response_data['orderId'])) {
        echo 'Order placed successfully! Order ID: ' . $response_data['orderId'];
    } else {
        echo 'Failed to place the order. Error: ' . $response;
    }
    
    // Close the cURL request
    curl_close($ch);
    
    dd($response_data);
```

Please what is wrong here, I have been pulling my hair with no luck